# Berkeley Java DB cache sizing

Tags: caching, berkeley-db-je

We're using JE 4.1.6 DPL. I set my environment max cache size using:

```
     EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig();
      envConfig.setCacheSize(cacheSize);
      StoreConfig storeConfig = new StoreConfig();

      envConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
      storeConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
      envConfig.setReadOnly(false);
      storeConfig.setReadOnly(false);
      envmntW = new Environment(rootDir, envConfig);
```

cacheSize =1000000000

After running for awhile I find that my cache grows beyond this setting

```
    StatsConfig statCfg = StatsConfig.DEFAULT;
    statCfg.setFast(true);
    cacheSize=envmntW.getStats(statCfg).getCacheTotalBytes();
```

How can this be?

Thanks
Chuck

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that this question had gone unanswered.

What do you get back from the getStats call?

In the future you may find that you get faster answers about Berkeley DB products on the Oracle Technology Network forums for Berkeley DB, which can be found [here](http://bit.ly/e5KwzV).